# many-to-many will trigger select on the many side even if these entities already loaded

Tags: hibernate

```
user(m:m)books

class user::
    @ManyToMany
    @BatchSize(size=100)
    public List<Book> books;

loadAllActiveUsers()
foreach user
   do(user.books)
```

Suppose user1 has books(1-5) and user2 has the same books.

When you call user.books hibernate will trigger a full query of load book even if these books already loaded.
Hibernate will not do nothing with this data because the entity already in session , but when book is "big entity" and when you load a lot of users than the redundant fetch become performance issue.

I will expect to have a way to define that hibernate will trigger a query on the association table and if this key is already in the session that don't trigger query for it.

Answer (score 0):

That's expected.

Suppose I load the user "John" first. And John owns the books "Moby Dick" and "Hamlet". Now I load the user "Mary". How is Hibernate supposed to know which books Mary owns? Maybe she owns Moby Dick, maybe not. Maybe she owns Hamlet, maybe not. Maybe she owns 200 other books, maybe not. So Hibernate executes a query to load all the books that Mary owns. If Mary happens to own a book that has previously been loaded, then only one instance of this book will exist in memory.

You can load the users with their books in a single query if you want:

```
select u from User u left join fetch u.books
```

Comment: hibernate can know this by trigger 2 step query : first load the association id from the association table then load the associations entity that weren't already loaded. In lot of many-to-many use cases the entity is associated with more than one owner so there is a chance that the associated entity already loaded.

Comment: fetch join is not a good idea when the entities has a one-to-many relation . 
any way even in case of simple entity you query will result 1M rows.